# Is it a coincidence that the circumference of the Earth in kilometers is almost $2^{12}$?

Tags: geodesy

The circumference of the Earth has been measured to be $40,075 \,\pu{km}$, which is only $21 \,\pu{km}$ from $40,096 = 2^{12}$. For reference, $40,075 \approx 2^{11.992}$. This is probably a strange coincidence, but originally a meter was set to be $1/10,000,000$-th of the distance from the North Pole to the Equator, so maybe there is a mathematical explanation.

Comment: $2^{12}$ is 4096 not 40,096

Comment: @uhoh Is it a coincidence that your name perfectly fits to the comment

Comment: So what is that in light years? Still a coincidence?

Answer (score 37):

Well, as others have pointed out we're a little off from $2^{12}$ kilometers. However, there is no coincidence that our world's circumference is close to $40000$ kilometers. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre):

> The metre was originally defined in 1793 as one ten-millionth of the distance from the equator to the North Pole along a great circle, so the Earth's circumference is approximately 40000 km.

Comment: Additional comment on this: another value that is not a coincidence is 21600=360*60 nautical miles, since the nautical mile originally measured a minute = 1/60 degree of latitude (or longitude at equator)

Answer (score 12):

There's something wrong with your math, $2^{12} \ = \ 4096$:

$2^x \ = \ 40\ 000$

$\therefore x\log2 \ = \ \log\ 40\ 000$

$\therefore x \ = \ \frac{\log\ 40000}{\log\ 2}$

$\therefore x \ = \ 15.28771$

Thus, $2^{15.28771} \ = \ 40\ 000$